# Upload XLSX or ZIP file using Apache CXF corrupts the file

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, cxf, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an XLSX file and the file gets corrupted once it reaches the server

Good file
�N�c�A�wo]6�9)}
"r��F1���6��a8�E�p�,��i����9J��~�6ʒ�2���y�b���ɵz`���E��ne�

Bad file ( after upload)
�N�c�A�wo]6�9)}
"r��F1���6��a8�E�p�,�i����9J��~�6ʒ�2���y�b���ɵz`���E�ne�

Client side JS to upload this file

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            
      $.ajax({  url:  'upload',
                data: formData,
                type: 'POST',
                enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                processData: false
            });
```

and at the server side using apache CXF

```js
@POST
  @Path("/upload")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void upload (@Multipart("file") Attachment attachment){
    
     InputStream inputStream = attachment.getDataHandler().getInputStream();
      File targetFile = new File("D://test.xlsx");
      OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
      int read = 0;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
      {
        outStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
      }            
      outStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: Because of the very bad formating of server data file you show it is hard to tell.  But It look like an encoding problem. Your server side java code do not manage encoding. The 'D:'  maybe related to Windows and an default encoding  Windows-1252. This could be far from the UT8 encoding of your browser.

Comment: and for IE to work the client side code should have contentType set to false

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no issue with CXF
2. No issue with JS library
3. we had a converter which does that encoding so from the above comment by @Galigator it is clear its an encoding issue